jenkins selenium project windows installer
I'm running Jenkins in the Windows installer Test cases are running without opening the browser but test cases are running
Browser: chrome
Starting ChromeDriver 125.0.6422.78 (14db42ec38aded3304a3e624a0a038e02956b87e-refs/branch-heads/6422@{#1088}) on port 38740
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

The browser should be visible
I want to run the test cases without a headless mode

Can you share more details? How are you initializing the browser? Any exceptions that you're facing during the executions? etc?
